# WebAPI to SOAP call impersonation

Tags: c#, .net, rest, wcf, soap

We are currently working on an extension service which is used to extend SharePoint functionalities.

At the moment we do have problems on impersonation the user. We provide a REST service which calls some SharePoint SOAP methods.

Basicly UI calls the REST Service (WebAPI) which uses Windows authentication / WebAPI code then runs impersonated and then should call the SOAP (WCF) API as the impersonated user.

What we did in code is this

```
using (((WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).Impersonate())
                {
                    SoapClient service = new SoapClient ();
                    service.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

....
```

Currently we receive the following error :

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was
>   'Negotiate,NTLM

Is there a trick to fix this in web.config ?

Hope you can help me out ;-) Thanks in forcast.

Kind regards.
Iki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did a lot of research and it was actually an infrastructural issue.
Due to the connection between the services “hoping” through multiple forest the impersonation fails.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also set the `ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential` to `System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultnetworkcredentials(v=vs.110).aspx

> The credentials returned by the DefaultNetworkCredentials property is applicable only for NTLM, negotiate, and Kerberos-based authentication.
>
> The credentials returned by DefaultNetworkCredentials represents the authentication credentials for the current security context in which the application is running. For a client-side application, these are usually the Windows credentials (user name, password, and domain) of the user running the application. For ASP.NET applications, the default network credentials are the user credentials of the logged-in user, or the user being impersonated.

Comment: Hey Subbu, thanks for your idea. Unfortunately it did not work.
using (((WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).Impersonate()) works for CSOM but not for SOAP